# ¿PHP y MYSQL: Por qué los datos del formulario no son guardados en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, formularios

soy principiante en código php y estoy tratando de realizar una conexión de un formulario a una base de datos, sin embargo, al momento de rellenar el formulario, los datos introducidos en este no son guardados en mi base de datos.

Aquí mi código php:

```
<?php 


    $conexionSql = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("No se pudo conectar con el servidor");
    mysqli_select_db($conexionSql, "bsharpproyect") or die ("No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos");

    if(isset($_POST['submitNuevoUsuario'])){
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $email  = $_POST['email'];
        $contrasenia = $_POST['contrasenia'];
        $contraseniaRepetir = $_POST['contraseniaRepetir'];
        $insertarDatos = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES ($usuario, $email, $contrasenia)";

        mysqli_query($conexionSql, $insertarDatos);
    }

    mysqli_close($conexionSql);
?>
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: cierra tus valores en comillas simples: `'$usuario', '$email', '$contrasenia'`

Comment: @CarlosQuitero Muchísimas gracias, era eso lo que faltaba :D.

Comment: Veo que ya te funciona, solo puntualizar que insertar los valores directamente concatenados **es vulnerable a INYECCIÓN SQL**, si estas empezando, mi recomendación es que aprendas a trabajar con sentencias preparadas. Vease: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propongo este código, el cual tiene las siguientes ventajas:

1. **Controla** todo el flujo del programa, recogiendo en una variable las eventualidades e imprimiéndola al final.
2. Usa consultas preparadas para **proteger** el código contra ataques de Inyección SQL.
3. **Optimiza** la conexión, seleccionando la base de datos al momento de crear el objeto. De ese modo no tiene que hacer una llamada suplementaria para elegir la base de datos.
4. Implementa el estilo **Orientado a Objetos**. Da más claridad y modernidad al código (también funcionará si lo quieres hacer en estilo procedural).
5. Se **priorizan** las variables y creación de objetos. Por ejemplo, es menos costoso comprobar el `isset`  que crear la conexión. Dado que la conexión sólo la intentaremos usar en caso de que haya datos en el POST, la creamos **luego** de esa comprobación, no antes, ya que podríamos estar conectando a la base de datos para nada.

Espero sea de utilidad.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitNuevoUsuario'])){
    $conexionSql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bsharpproyect");
    if($conexionSql){
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $email  = $_POST['email'];
        $contrasenia = $_POST['contrasenia'];
        $contraseniaRepetir = $_POST['contraseniaRepetir'];
        /* crear una sentencia preparada */
        $insertarDatos = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario,email,contrasenia) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conexionSql->prepare($insertarDatos);
        if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $usuario, $email, $contrasenia);
            /* ejecutar la consulta */
            $stmt->execute();
            $msgOutput="Filas insertadas: ".$stmt->affected_rows;
            /* cerrar sentencia */
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            $msgOutput="Error preparando la consulta: ".$conexionSql->error;
        }
        /* cerrar conexión */
        $conexionSql->close();
    } else {
        $msgOutput="Error, no se pudo conectar a la base de datos: ".$conexionSql->connect_error;
    }
} else {
    $msgOutput="No se postearon los datos correctamente";
}
echo $msgOutput;
?>
```